# After Expo eas update app is crashing for managed workflow

Tags: react-native, expo, release, eas

I updated my expo version from 45 to 47 and created a build using `eas` and tested it on the device, it's working fine.

But the app crashes(iOS and Android both) when doing OTA using `eas update`.Also not getting any error while releasing via OTA.

Tried this [Github](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) solution but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your app.json file to do:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion" //This can be the issue
    }
  }
}
```

- Also try updating your cli version e.g `npm install -g eas-cli`
- If the app is still crashing after the fixes mentioned above most likely it means the update is not compatible with SDK 47, you can run `expo doctor` and try to fix any dependency warnings.

Take a look here as well:
https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/runtime-versions/#avoiding-crashes-with-incompatible-updates